# How to manage placement of blog articles in omega regions

Tags: theming, nodes

I want to be able to control which omega region blog entries (individual blog articles) are placed. They appear to be in the content-zone, but I have not seen how to control which actual region they are contained within.

Answer (score 0):

All content ends up in the **Content** region.  If you need something different, then I think g you have two options.

One, you can try to use a process function to move the content to a different region withing the zone.  The function would be `function mytheme_alpha_process_zone (&$variables)` and you would place it in "process/process-zone.inc".  I have no idea if this would actually work, but it is worth a shot.

Two, you could use one of the various techniques for changing layout based on content type.  Personally, I am a fan of [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), but you could also try [Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta) (which plays nicely with [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega)).